# Dagger/MissingBinding java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends ViewModel>,Provider<ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, dagger-2, dagger

This is how I'm trying to provide my `ViewModelFactory`:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

And this is how I'm binding the `ViewModelFactory`:

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule  {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun mainViewModel(viewModel: MainViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

I'm receiving the following error during build:

```
di/Injector.java:9: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

From my `Activity` I'm trying to receive the `ViewModelFactory` this way:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging a little bit more I found the issue.
It's completely un-related to the code I'm using. It regards `Kotlin 1.3.30`.

[Here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478) some more information about it.

Downgrading to `Kotlin 1.3.21` resolved the problem.

Comment: According to [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478), user [bleeding182](https://github.com/bleeding182) suggested [a workaround](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478#issuecomment-484825244) to instead refactor `ViewModelKey` to Java. It works for me.

Comment: Hi, please check the solution below.

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same issue recently. 
**Version**
*Kotlin:1.3.40*
*Dagger:2.23.2*
I tried following the solutions mentioned in this post and [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478)

but none seemed to work. The annotation processor of Dagger is not playing well with KAPT and for the same reason, the builds are failing. This is also updated on Kotlin [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30979) too.

For me, converting both the `ViewModelKey` and `ViewModelFactory` to java worked.
For Dagger, the tracking issue can be found [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1540).

**Update**
Adding `@JvmSuppressWildcards` fixed the issue. Code looks like this:

```
private val providers: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
```

Comment: All my code was in kotlin.Converting both the ViewModelKey and ViewModelFactory to java worked. Thanks. Adding @JvmSuppressWildcards not worked

Comment: This is amazing my brother.

Comment: You da man.  @JvmSuppressWildcards for the win.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is tricky. After investing entire day I figured the working solution to use `ViewModeFactory` with `Dagger2` for dependency injection of `view models`.

You need to change map key type to `Class<*>` in your `ViewModeFactory` constructor.

Example

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class CustomViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(
    val viewModelMap: Map<Class<*>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = viewModelMap[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in viewModelMap) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("View model class not found in ViewModelModule $modelClass")
        }
        try {
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

AppComponent interface

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ViewModelModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun getViewModelMap(): Map<Class<*>, ViewModel>

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Module class

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @ClassKey(FruitsViewModel::class)
    @IntoMap
    abstract fun bindFruitsViewModel(fruitsViewModel: FruitsViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Now you inject any object into your ViewModel constructor which inherits android ViewModel

Answer (score -2):

First of all ViewModelFactory shouldn't be a Singleton. Anyway to fix this you should have:

- a ViewModelFactory

  `class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
      private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
  ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
      override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
          val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
              modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
          }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
          try {
              @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
              return creator.get() as T
          } catch (e: Exception) {
              throw RuntimeException(e)
          }
      }
  }`
- bind this factory in your module class

  `@Binds
  abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory`
- have a ViewModelKey

  `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
  @Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
  @MapKey
  annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)`
- bind your viewModel in the desired module

  `@Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
  abstract fun bindCustomViewModel(viewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel`
- then implement and use your viewModel

  `@Inject
  lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory`

  `private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }`

This solution is tested with `Kotlin 1.3.72` and latest version of `Dagger2`.
Also please check at https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Update: Now Hilt suppress this problem. Please use @ViewModelInject. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack