# Dagger MissingBinding error when injecting ViewModels

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm new to dagger and want to use it for injecting ViewModels (along with other objects such as repositories). When I try to compile the app this error is shown:

```
e: C:\Project\...\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\myapp\di\AppComponent.java:16: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.myapp.di.ViewModelFactory(viewModels)
      com.myapp.di.ViewModelFactory is injected at
          com.myapp.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
      androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          com.myapp.ui.activity.MainActivity.viewModelFactory
      com.myapp.ui.activity.MainActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myapp.di.AppComponent ? com.myapp.di.ActivityModule_ContributeMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myapp.di.AppComponent ? com.myapp.di.ActivityModule_ContributeItemsFrament.ItemsFragmentSubcomponent]
```

Maybe there is one silly mistake that prevents compilation.

Dagger component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, DatabaseModule::class, ViewModelModule::class, ActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: MyCustomApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyCustomApplication)
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Inject
    lateinit var app: Application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppContext(): Context = app.applicationContext
}
```

ActivityModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMainFrament(): MainFragment
}
```

ViewModelModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
    abstract fun mainViewModel(mainViewModel: MainViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>)
: ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = viewModels[modelClass]
                ?: viewModels.asIterable().firstOrNull { modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key) }?.value
                ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        return try {
            creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

The application class:

```
class MyCustomApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerMainComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector() = activityInjector
}
```

MainViewModel (**note that it extends from `AndroidViewModel` and requires an application context**):

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(app: Application, private val repository: MainRepository)
    : AndroidViewModel(app) {
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue combining `Android X` and `Kotlin version 1.3.0`, Dagger won't be able to create `MultiBindings`. To solve the problem I just followed next steps:

a) **Update Kotlin version to 1.3.31** on `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin: 1.3.31"
}
```

b) **Clean and rebuild** the project, to do so, execute the following command in a terminal:

```
$ gradle clean build
```

or if using gradle wrapper:

```
 $ ./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Thank you. It was exactly that. Now the app cannot be compiled because of a dependency cycle which is probably a programming error: `e: C:\Project\...\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\myapp\di\AppComponent.java:16: error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public abstract interface AppComponent ...`
`.
I will post it as another question.

Comment: curious how this was solved, as the `MainActivity` does not implement `HasAndroidInjector`

Comment: Please check at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669810/dagger-missingbinding-java-util-mapjava-lang-class-extends-viewmodel-provide/62260147#62260147

Answer (score 1):

I have tried updating the `kotlin-gradle-plugin` to `1.3.31` but it didn't work for me.

After spending some time on the internet, I have found the following solution which is working for me.

Try adding `@JvmSuppressWildcards` before `Provider<ViewModel>` like following:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideViewModelFactory(creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>): ViewModelFactory {
    return ViewModelFactory(creators)
}
```

And in `ViewModelFactory` as well.

```
class ViewModelFactory(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) :
        ViewModelProvider.Factory
```